# Real-time serial I/O with Boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, real-time, boost-asio

We have some working code to talk to serial port using Boost asio. One thing we have been observing is that this communication is not real-time and there is sometime significant latency.

We want to receive and send all data on serial port with list amount of latency. That means we want to avoid any buffering while reading and writing, any batching because of lack of explicit flushing calls or avoid Boost async calls that might use its own threads with normal priority adding to latency.

Is there any sample code that uses Boost asio for serial port communication with least amount of latency for real-time scenario? If sample code is for TCP/UDP port, I guess we might still able to adapt it...

Answer (score 2):

ASIO doesn't really provide that sort of stuff. You'll be better off going direct with serial, it's not like it's exactly taxing on the CPU.

Disabling input buffering is something like `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);`, now reads always return as soon as possible even if blocking i/o is on.

Forcing writes to send is something like `tcdrain()`.

It's been many years since I last wrote serial i/o code, but the above is a good head start for you.